# Reference to behaviour when concating numbers

Tags: perl

```
perl -Mstrict -wle 'print 82.46.67.88.":1"'
```

output is

```
R.CX:1 # chr(82) . chr(46) etc.
```

I've noticed that there should be at least three numbers in order to trigger such behavior.
Where does perldoc mention it?

Comment: Example found at http://perlobfuscator.com/decode-stunnix.pl

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perl56delta.html#Support-for-strings-represented-as-a-vector-of-ordinals

Comment: And http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Scalar-value-constructors (see "Version Strings" heading)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are "Version Strings", which first appeared in 5.6 (http://perldoc.perl.org/perl56delta.html#Support-for-strings-represented-as-a-vector-of-ordinals)

I thought they'd been deprecated and removed several versions ago, but apparently they're still around. http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Scalar-value-constructors